# How to test enum validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a variable that has a specific set of answer options. In my model I have:

```
validates :article_type,  presence: true
enum article_type:        [ :type1, :type2, :type3 ]
```

I have the following model test:

```
test "type test" do
  assert @article.valid?
  @article.article_type= "type1"
  assert @article.valid?
  @article.article_type= "type5"
  assert_not @article.valid?
end
```

**Error:** The line `@article.article_type= "type5"` generates the error: 
`ArgumentError: 'type5' is not a valid article_type`.

For all other sorts of validations where I include invalid data and then use `assert_not` these kinds of tests work. Why not in this case? How should I rewrite this model test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the explanation from Rails team: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13971

If you want to test that invalid values are rejected, use `assert_raises` to expect the `ArgumentError`

Comment: Thanks! It worked with: `assert_raises ArgumentError do` ; `@article.article_type = "type5"` ; `end`.

Answer (score 0):

```
test "type test" do
  assert @article.valid?
  
  @article.article_type = "type1"
  assert @article.valid?

  assert_raises ArgumentError do
    @article.article_type = "type5"
    assert_not @article.valid?
  end
end
```